# WP Walker using custom css classes

Tags: php, menus, walker

In order to make a navigation (from scratch), I've been altering the output of the walker. Currently i am trying to find a way to include the 'Optional CCS Class' (found in Appearances -> Menu's in the WP Admin) to the output item menu (start_el). I am starting to doubt if it is possible at this point. Which is why i would like your help. I am using this array to determine if a item has children or is active:

```
$usedclasses = array(
    (in_array('current-menu-item', $item->classes) ? 'current-menu-item' : ''),
    (in_array('menu-item-has-children', $item->classes) ? 'menu-item-has-children' : ''),
    ($depth % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even')
); $class_names = 'class="' . implode( ' ', $usedclasses ) . '"';
```

Is there a way to add the custom added classes without having to include all clutter classes? So trying to avoid using:

```
$class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args, $depth ) );
$class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure you want to do it like this, but just in case, you can use the filter `nav_menu_css_class` :

```
function my_special_nav_class( $classes, $item ) {

   if ( is_single() && $item->title == 'Blog' ) {
      $classes[] = 'special-class';
   }

   return $classes;

}

add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'my_special_nav_class', 10, 2 );
```

You'll find more example [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/nav_menu_css_class)

Comment: This certainly is a way to do this, though would force me to add all items i want to use this for manually in the functions.php . I would rather have a way for the Nav_Dynamic_Walker to use the (standard) optional CSS classes that Wordpress provides. This will be a good fallback method if i cannot though.

Comment: No, you can have an array of the classes you want to add and loop through before returns $classes

Comment: The only way i seem to be able to apply this is by making an array that goes through the title attributes like this: $optionalclasses = array( ($item->attr_title == 'contact' ? 'contact' : ''));

Comment: Okay if i am not mistaken it is not possible to get just the optional class from the classes array ($item->classes). Though i found a way around this by adding the title as an class: ( ! empty($item->attr_title) ? $item->attr_title : '')